# Tracking functions on stack in C

Tags: c, function, stack

I am taking the first dive into the waters of stack memory trace so I need your help. Here is my problem for which I need your tips:

I have two functions: login and logout(). There is one simple condition:

- If I call login() to create a session, then somewhere in my program, logout() should be called otherwise there should be an error generated.

I believe that that I can not do it on compile time so I have to do it on runtime(I can be wrong).

The problem is that how do I find out that logout() is called in my program before the main() returns and generate error if it is not called.

I was thinking that at the runtime, Every function that I call after login() should check whether it is the last function call and then look whether the logout() was called ever before or not.

So How would I know at runtime that a certain function is the last function my program called before the main() returns?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check out the `atexit` function.

Answer (score 3):

one way, perhaps not the nicest, is to use a variable loggedIn = 1, and pass a reference to it so logout() can set it to zero. check that it's zero before return from main().

after a function returns, its address has already been popped from the stack.

Comment: I had this method in my mind but I wanted to try something in which I would interact with stack for educational purposes.

Comment: after a function returns the stack will no longer contain a pointer to it.

Comment: @jcomeau_ictx, At least, it won't after it gets overwritten by calling the next function. On most (all?) platforms it is just adjusting the stack pointer so the data will be there for a while afterwards.

Comment: I sure wouldn't trust it! but it can't hurt to test.

Comment: @JewelThief, For educational purposes, you can just write data to various places on the stack. The results can be very educational in telling you that you don't want to interact with the stack.